# Scanner(System.in).nextLine() behaving weirdly

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a simple program dealing with user input. I am using Scanner(System.in).nextLine(). The program allows you to enter a number and then prints this to the console. The problem is that the program pauses here unless you enter another number. If you do this the rest of the code runs as expected. The value of the accountNumberIn variable is set to the first number you enter. I would really appreciate any help. This is the code.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BankAccount acc1 = new BankAccount("12345" , "fran pugh");
        BankAccount acc2 = new BankAccount("67890" , "henry lee");
        String accountNumber1 = acc1.getAccountNumber();
        String accountNumber2 = acc2.getAccountNumber();
        String accountNumberIn;
        double depositAmount;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter your account number");
        accountNumberIn = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("account number is " + accountNumberIn);
        // Program pauses here until you enter another number
        // but the first number is the value of the variable accountNumberIn

        depositAmount = validateAccountNumber(accountNumberIn, accountNumber1, accountNumber2);
        depositAmount(depositAmount, accountNumberIn, accountNumber1, accountNumber2, acc1, acc2);
        
    }
    public static double validateAccountNumber(String accountNumberIn, String accountNumber1, String accountNumber2) 
    {
        Scanner d = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        double depositAmount = d.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("validating account");
        
        while(!accountNumberIn.equals(accountNumber1) && !accountNumberIn.equals(accountNumber2))
        {
            
            System.out.println("incorrect account number. Please re-enter");

            accountNumberIn = s.nextLine();;
            //validateAccountNumber(accountNumberIn, accountNumber1, accountNumber2);
            
        }
            System.out.println("Please enter your deposit amount");
            depositAmount = EasyScanner.nextDouble();
            return depositAmount;

    }
        
        public static void depositAmount(double depositAmount, String accountNumberIn, String accountNumber1, String accountNumber2, BankAccount acc1, BankAccount acc2 )
        {
            int currentAccount = 0;
            char ans;
        
            if(accountNumberIn.equals(accountNumber1)) {
                currentAccount = 1;
                acc1.deposit(depositAmount);
                
                System.out.println("Deposited in account number " + accountNumber1);
            } else if (accountNumberIn.equals(accountNumber2))
            {
                currentAccount = 2;
                acc2.deposit(depositAmount);
                System.out.println("Deposited in account number " + accountNumber2);
            } 
            
            
            do
            {
                System.out.println("Would you like to make another deposit y/n");
                ans = EasyScanner.nextChar();
                if(ans == 'y') 
                {
                    System.out.println("Please enter your deposit amount");
                    depositAmount = EasyScanner.nextDouble();
                    if (currentAccount == 1 ) {
                        acc1.deposit(depositAmount);
                    } else if (currentAccount == 2)
                    {
                        acc2.deposit(depositAmount);
                    }
                }
            } while(ans == 'y'); 
            printDetails(acc1, acc2);
        }   
        
        public static void printDetails(BankAccount acc1, BankAccount acc2) {
            
            System.out.println("Account Number: " + acc1.getAccountNumber());
            System.out.println("Account Name: " + acc1.getAccountName());
            System.out.println("Account Balance: " + acc1.getBalance());
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Account Number: " + acc2.getAccountNumber());
            System.out.println("Account Name: " + acc2.getAccountName());
            System.out.println("Account Balance: " + acc2.getBalance());
        }

}
```

Comment: "// Program pauses here" are you sure? What do `validateAccountNumber` and `depositAmount` look like?

Comment: As an unrelated aside, your program would be more readable if you declared variables only where you need them, instead of declaring them at the top of a method.

Comment: Once I got rid of all the undefined things, it worked fine for me. Are you using Scanner anywhere else?

Comment: I have posted the rest of the code above. The code definitely pauses, it doesn't quit and if you enter another number it all runs fine.  Thank you for the tip on the variables, I will start doing that.

Comment: `validateAccountNumbers` starts with a call to `nextDouble`. Are you sure it's not stopping there?

Comment: Ooops yes! It is stopping there!

Comment: Oh my god so simple! I'm so sorry everyone, thanks for your help!